# Upgrading Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform to version 2.0.1 causes CVE-2017-0248 to be reported by WhiteSource Bolt

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, roslyn

I added WhiteSource Bolt to my Azure DevOps pipeline and noticed that it was reporting CVE-2017-0247, CVE-2017-0248, CVE-2017-0249 vulnerabilities after I upgraded the Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform nuget package from version 2.0.0 to 2.0.1

The issue is being caused by an old version of System.Net.Http (4.6.24705.1) being included in the bin\roslyn folder.

To keep it simple I have created a new empty web project which just has the Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform nuget package. I started using version 2.0.0 of the package. When building using this package the roslyn folder has version 2.8.2.62916 of the C# compiler which doesn't have the dependency on System.Net.Http. When using this version all files in this folder have a date modified of 24/05/2018

I then updated the Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform nuget package to version 2.0.1. After building the solution the roslyn folder had version 2.9.0.63208 of the C# compuler which has a dependency on System.Net.Http. The files in the roslyn folder have a variety of dates from 2018, 2017 and 2016.

Whitesource is detecting the old version of System.Net.Http and flagging it up since it is effected by the above mentioned CVEs.

I have uploaded my code to https://github.com/rubenmamo/CVE-2017-0248-Test

Unfortunately I don't really understand how roslyn is used in Asp.Net projects and am not sure whether it is safe to use the 2.0.1 version of the Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform nuget package. It looks odd that Microsoft would have released a package in September 2017 with such an issue without fixing it.

I'm not sure I'm missing something :|

Comment: Please file a bug on this github repo https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider

This is where the source for Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform lives

Comment: Created https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider/issues/84

Comment: Hello @RubenMamo Can you please help to fix this issue. I am facing in my asp.net web API application which is consuming Microsoft.codedom.providers.dotnetcompilerplatform.2.0.1

Comment: @RubenMamo did you fix that problem? I am trying to add `System.Net.Http` version 4.2.0.0 to my project, but because of `DotNetCompilerPlatform` it's referencing 4.1.1.0 instead.